# App crashes on spinner item click

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have this code for my simple spinner:

```
 private Spinner spnr_gender;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_complete_profile);

    //GUI
    spnr_gender = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnr_finish_gender);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> gender_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.strs_gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    gender_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnr_gender.setAdapter(gender_adapter);
    spnr_gender.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);

}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String selectChoice = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), selectChoice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

What I want is to toast what the user has selected on the spinner. My string array in the strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="strs_gender">
    <item>Male</item>
    <item>Female</item>
</string-array>
```

When running the app it just crashed.
I can't find anything on the logcat but my suspect is this line `spnr_gender.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you pass wrong parameter in adapter. parameter should be like this ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
spnr_gender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Instead of

```
spnr_gender.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);
```

[**`setOnItemSelectedListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener))

> `void setOnItemSelectedListener (AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener)`
>
> Register a callback to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been selected.

**EDIT**

Use this

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> gender_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.strs_gender));
```

Instead of this

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> gender_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.strs_gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

**[Spinner example](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-spinner-example)**

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

private Spinner spnr_gender;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_complete_profile);

    //GUI
    spnr_gender     =   (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr_finish_gender);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> gender_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.strs_gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    gender_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnr_gender.setAdapter(gender_adapter);
    spnr_gender.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);

}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String selectChoice = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), selectChoice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Only (this) context while declaring item click listener
Do not **cast** with `(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)` with it.

Use only

```
spnr_gender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

make it in this fashion

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```